# safari iOS 13 text zoom - fix for web pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, safari

I have installed the developer version of iOS i.e. 13 to check the compatibility of our website and I see that safari now has a feature to zoom in/out web pages for readability. I see that most of pages or now broken if we zoom in. I want to fix this issue before the official release of iOS-13

I checked their own official website which is handled very nicely but they are actually not increasing the font size they just zoom in the page.

I tried various properties with this meta tag as well:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){ 
    html,body {
        min-width: 320px;
    }
}
```

Actually when you zoom-in, that means you are reducing your html and body width.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code in `css`:

```
html {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}
```

Thanks